# Cannot find weblogic maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, weblogic

I follow this tutorial to install weblogic plugin:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/maven_deployer.htm
and now I can see this jar in my local repository
but when I run mvn weblogic:deploy I have still this error:

```
No versions are present in the repository for the artifact with a range [9.0,11.0)
  weblogic:weblogic:jar:null

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  codehaus.org (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org)

Path to dependency: 
    1) org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.9.3
```

maven setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <localRepository>/path...</localRepository>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ext</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>java.net</id>
                    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
                    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>Mirrors.ibiblio.org</id>
                    <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>mojo-executor-repository</id>
                    <url>http://mojo-executor.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
                    <name>Springframework Maven Repository</name>
                    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>java.net</id>
                    <name>Java.net Repository for Maven2</name>
                    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1/</url>
                    <layout>legacy</layout>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
                    <url>http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: Have you tried mvn -Pext weblogic:deploy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check your settings.xml file. You need to add the following into your settings.xml 
   
     
      com.oracle.weblogic

Also you need to follow a two step process for installing the weblogic maven plugin jar. First use the jarbuilder tool for generating the uber jar.

```
 java -jar wljarbuilder.jar -profile weblogic-maven-plugin
```

This command would create a 65MB jar named weblogic-maven-plugin jar. Now you need to provision your jar into the repo. Use the command and remove the pom.xml from the jar.

```
 jar xvf MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic-maven-plugin.jar META-INF/maven/com.oracle.weblogic/weblogic-maven-plugin/pom.xml

 cp MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/META-INF/maven/com.oracle.weblogic/weblogic-maven-plugin/pom.xml MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib
```

The next step is most important. You need to be in the MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib directory for this.

```
 mvn install
```

And then you need to do a ....

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile="MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic-maven-plugin.jar -DpomFile="pom.xml"
```

[weblogic goal prefix with weblogic maven plugins](http://buttso.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-weblogic-prefix-with-weblogic.html)

Comment: I did that and afterwards I am having issues trying to call a web service from a JUnit test. There is an NPE Exception during WSDL Parsing. Any idea what can cause this behaviour?

Comment: and finally sync push the oracle jars in your local repo C:\share\weblogic\wls1212\wlserver\server\lib>mvn -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=c:\share\weblogic\wls1212\ com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -X >push.txt see http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm

Comment: yes thats right, i added all steps as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not referring to the Oracle WebLogic Maven Plugin.  In the error you see this: org.codehaus.mojo:weblogic-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.9.3.  Perhaps you were trying the codehaus plugin and need to update your pom with the coordinates to the Oracle one that you installed.  For example:

```
groupId=com.oracle.weblogic
artifactId=weblogic-maven-plugin
version=10.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what i did for weblogic 12c

This basically

- Builds client jars
- Builds oralce maven plugin jar
- Installs them in local repo
- Then uses the sync plugin to push tons of oracle jars in local repo - including ejb, jsf, jpa, weblogic 200+ jars

See
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm

if you a developer using zip installation follow these instruction to install weblogic zip

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/wls_12c_netbeans_install/wls_12c_netbeans_install.html

clean /home/oracle/.m2/repository dir

```
cd /home/oracle/wls12120/wlserver/server/lib

cp weblogic.jar weblogic-classes.jar
java -jar wljarbuilder.jar -profile weblogic-maven-plugin
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=weblogic-maven-plugin.jar -DpomFile=pom.xml
mvn install
cd /home/oracle/wls12120/oracle_common/plugins/maven/com/oracle/maven/oracle-maven-sync/12.1.2
mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync.12.1.2.jar
mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push  -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=/home/oracle/wls12120  -Doracle-maven-sync.testingOnly=false -X
```

For windows I wrote this script that you can run from home dir
tested in 12.1.2

```
cls
echo about to delete %USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository
pause
del /Q/F %USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository

set WL_HOME=%~dp0
set ORACLE_HOME=%~dp0
set WLV=12.1.2


set w

set M2_HOME=%WL_HOME%\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.maven_3.0.4

setlocal
pushd
cd %WL_HOME%\wlserver\server\lib
cp weblogic.jar weblogic-classes.jar
call java -jar wljarbuilder.jar -profile weblogic-maven-plugin
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=weblogic-maven-plugin.jar -DpomFile=pom.xml
echo on
call mvn install

pause

echo on
cd %WL_HOME%\oracle_common\plugins\maven\com\oracle\maven\oracle-maven-sync\%WLV%
echo on
call mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync.%WLV%.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync.%WLV%.jar
echo on
call mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push  -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=%WL_HOME% -Doracle-maven-sync.testingOnly=false -X

popd
```

Answer (score 0):

mvn -X com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -DoracleHome=%ORACLE_HOME% -Doracle-maven-sync.testingOnly=false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).