# Weblogic 12 maven plugin

Tags: maven-2, weblogic12c

I have downloaded weblogic 12 `wls1213_devzip_update1.zip` and extraxted all files (under `windows`) in `D:\Development\wls12130`

I'm now trying to build the `weblogic-maven-plugin` according to this [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/maven_deployer.htm#DEPGD379)

So I go to `d:\Development\wls12130\wlserver\server\lib` but it is impossible to use the `wljarbuilder.jar` because it does not exists.
There is only a `wljarbuilder.jar.pack`.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to run config to unpack read the readme listed on download site
http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/12c/wls/1213/README_WIN_UP2.txt?AuthParam=1430592315_d5c6abb7c6d0cb572f474d3cae3c00bd

and then setup

I havent tried it on latest update1 version yet but here are the steps

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23546274/255139